# Relay parameters to Okta and retrieve from IDP flow

Tags: python, okta

I am trying to implement SSO with Okta in Python Flask but I don't see anywhere in their docs where I could pass in a parameter and retrieve it back in a successful login response. I currently 2 endpoints modeled after https://github.com/jpf/okta-pysaml2-example/blob/master/app.py.

A SP initiated method which gets the parameter I'm passing in and sends a SAML request to Okta.

An IDP initiated method, where on a valid login, Okta sends a SAML response and I redirect to a URL where I want to append the initial parameter passed in. Is this possible?

Comment: It's not so much a parameter, rather you pass a relay_state. That relay_state is a URL which may include parameters.)

Comment: i see, i have implemented this method of passing in a parameter through the relay state and it works fine. however, if someone were to login via the Okta app, I'd like this parameter to be set as well.. something like a token to indicate where to finally redirect the user: the website or the mobile app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where the user goes post sign-in is determined by the Relay State. It's an opaque value, so any parameter you want to set can be part of that. For simplicity, Relay State could be an encoded URL. Alternatively, it could be something your SP knows how to translate/decrypt to redirect the user to the next state (i.e., page).

For SP-initiated requests, you (the SP) provide the Relay State.

For IDP-initiated requests, you should be able to set the default relay state. Specifically for okta, set the Default Relay State under Application - Settings - Sign On Methods for the application in question.

(If you want okta to send you to different places, say "main" vs. "admin console" part of your SP application, you either need multiple okta applications, or you send the user to the same place & your SP figures out where to send them "next", perhaps based on logged in user name, or via an Attribute Value Assertion included with the authentication response.)

Comment: Thanks, I was looking for an answer that would help the Okta app distinguish whether a user was on the Okta website vs app and depending on that, allow us to input a parameter to let the server know whether to direct the user to my website or mobile application. However, I spoke with Okta support and I don't believe this is possible. Aside from this, the RelayState is indeed what we need to use to pass parameters in but by implementing this as so, launching my app from Okta will always direct them to only one place; either my website or mobile app.

Comment: I've updated my answer. Technically, the Relay State isn't a URL: It can be, but it doesn't have to be. Your SP will get this Relay State value on authenticated login from IdP & you can do what you like with it: For security reasons, you might encrypt the RelayState you pass SP to IdP: IdP send it back to you, you decrypt it and act upon in.

Comment: Thats true. I ended up just implementing a buffer page that would read in the user agent and if from a mobile device, direct them to the mobile site or mobile app. Otherwise they'll be directed to the web site